# How to get the user names and domains of all locally stored user profiles in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, user-profile

How to retrieve the user names and domains of all user profiles stored on a computer using VB.NET? the Code below does exactly what I need, but in VBScript. How can I do the same in VB.NET?

```
    Const HKLM = &H80000002
    Const profiles = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

    sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

    reg.EnumKey(HKLM, profiles, subkeys)
    For Each sid In subkeys
        reg.GetStringValue(HKLM, profiles & "\" & sid, "ProfileImagePath", path)
        path = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path)
        If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
            acct = wmi.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & sid & "'")
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(acct.ReferencedDomainName & "\" & acct.AccountName)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: So what was the question?

Comment: SO is not a code translation service.

Answer (score 2):

A simple query to the Win32_UserAccount will give the info required

```
Sub Main
    Dim oquery =  new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount")
    Dim mosearcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery)
    Dim moc = mosearcher.Get()
    for each mo in moc
        Console.WriteLine(mo.Properties("Caption").Value.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(mo.Properties("Domain").Value.ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

Requires a reference to System.Management.dll and the import of System.Management

Comment: Sadly I've been there. With more than 20.000 users in the domain the "Win32_UserAccount" just goes longrunning. Thats why the example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310594/113116 is the one I want. But in VB :-)

Comment: If I understand correctly then you don't need to check the ProfileList in the local machine, you need to use ActiveDirectory because it is unlikely that all 20.000 users have been logged locally

Comment: Hi Steve :-) I just wish somebody here would be so kind as to show how to get my code running in VB. The above code does not work. My form never shows.

Comment: My code above (well the code in my answer) is not for a WinForms application, it is just a console app. You need to take the inner part and add to a click button, remove the Console.WriteLine and use whatever interface control you like to display the output.

Comment: I did. Well I put it in my main_Load and replaced the Console with CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(mo.Properties("Domain").Value.ToString() & "\" & mo.Properties("Caption").Value.ToString())

Comment: Perhaps you could use `mo.Properties("Name").Value.ToString()` instead of "Caption" to keep the two parts separated. I suggest you to install LinqPAD and try with mo.Dump() method to see the various properties available.

Comment: Youre right about the mo.Properties("Name").Value.ToString()  I've now tried it with a button and the form just goes iresponsive. I then added a counter that shows that the "for each mo" just keeps running :-/ (now at 12.000) somehow it does not only find local users...

Comment: I now made it stop at 100, and looked throgh the listbox, and my first theory is correct. It just starts chewing through the whole AD... that's why if I could only figure out how to make the WMI example (at the top) work in VB, i would be very happy :-)